# Could you simplify the following passage so that it won't be hard to grasp and more, please?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Health care providers **other than** the vaccine administrator treating a patient for a suspected adverse event should notify the vaccine administrator and provide the information about the adverse event to allow the vaccine administrator to complete VAERS form to meet the vaccine administrator's legal responsibility.

When it says "other than" does it mean that someone else must intervene or not? Is it mandatory to a new doctor other than the administrator to complete the form? what does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

I'll add a bit of context and an example.

If you experience side effects to a vaccine, the person administering the vaccine (let's say your family doctor) has to record it in a VAERS (Vaccine Adverse Effect Reporting System) form.

Imagine you took a vaccine from your family doctor and a few hours later got so sick that you decided to go to a hospital instead of your own physician. In this case, the hospital is a "health care provider other than the vaccine administrator" and they are treating a possible case of adverse effect. The hospital should warn your family doctor, so that your doctor can complete the form.

So to answer your question: if the VA(vaccine administrator) intervenes, they fill out the form. If someone else does, they notify the VA and the VA fills out the form. Your VA is responsible for recording all adverse effects and reporting them to the vaccine producers.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is unnecessarily complicated by the **other than** restrictive clause and by its lack of punctuation.

Those health care providers who have treated a patient for a suspected adverse reaction to a vaccine must notify the vaccine administrator and provide information about the event, so that the administrator can complete a VAERS form, as it is  legally required to do.

The **other than** means "except for".  In this sentence, the meaning is weird: why would the vaccine administrator notify itself?

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is clear for me, although complicated. The meaning is:

1. The vaccine administrator is legally obliged to fill the VAERS form.
2. The patient can be treated by vaccine administrator or someone else.
3. If some health care provider other than vaccine administrator is
   treating a patient with suspected vaccine adverse event it is
   obliged to notify the administrator, so that he can fill the form.

The clause "other than" ... well, I think it is necessary to prevent interpretation that "EVERY health care provider should notify vaccine administrator ...", which could be understood by some silly clerk/inspector that vaccine administrator should notify himself in writing, just because this act says so, doubling the amount of documentation. (This assumption is based on personal experience ;) )

I would leave all names in well established form (such as "adverse event"), and omit obvious part about information:

> Health care providers other than the vaccine administrator treating a
>   patient for a suspected adverse event should notify the vaccine
>   administrator and provide the information necessary to complete VAERS
>   form by vaccine administrator, to meet his legal responsibility.

Other version:

> Health care providers other than the vaccine administrator treating a
>   patient for a suspected adverse event should notify the vaccine
>   administrator, who is legally responsible for completing VAERS form, 
>   and provide the information necessary to complete the form.